# C typedef'd array - What's the initial value?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I know the initial value of an array is 0 when defined as static and undefined otherwise, but I'm not entirely sure if this is the same way when the array is typedef'd. I think so, but I want to confirm it.

Just to make it clear, I mean something like this:

```
typedef float vector3[3];

int main (int argc, char* argv) {
    vector3 vec;
    static vector3 vec2;
}
```

The vec variable would be undefined, wouldn't it? What about vec2? It should be all 0, right?

Comment: `typedef` is only so you can get a simpler name.  The compiler pretends you typed out the whole thing anyway.

Comment: No, the initial value is unspecific, not undefined. It has whatever value is found at the memory location or whatever value pleases to the compiler. It would only be undefined behavior if this value happens to be a trap representation for the base type.

Comment: Bad choice of words on my side, I thought it was ok to call the initial value undefined, but I see the difference. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the values in `vec` would be undefined; the values in `vec2` would be all zeroes.

The use of a `typedef` makes no difference to the behaviour of the type when variables are defined or declared.

Comment: The values in `vec` would be unspecific. This *could* lead to undefined behavior if it were by coincidence a trap representation for the underlying base type (here `float`).

Comment: It could only lead to undefined behaviour if you read the values before storing something legitimate in them.  If you ensure that the values are initialized before reading, there is no risk of undefined behaviour.  Of course, the question implies that the code might be planning to read the values before ensuring that they are initialized, and that leads to undefined behaviour, but the values being undefined does not of itself lead to undefined behaviour.  So, I think that 'undefined' (of values) and 'undefined behaviour' (that might result from reading undefined values) are separate.

Comment: Only that there simply is already a different term for that, "indeterminate value".

Answer (score 1):

`typedef`s have absolutely no effect on the semantics of the code.  This includes initial values.